"The tourists, who were most of them foreigners, had been hoarded onto a cattle truck." — Why is "most of them foreigners" grammatical?
the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 1359:

from the passage above:

(1) The tourists, most of them foreigners, had been hoarded onto a cattle truck. – The supplement "most of them foreigners" is comparable in function to a relative clause: compare "who were most of them foreigners" ( or "most of whom were foreigners").

one of the sentences the textbook suggested for the comparison:
(2) The tourists, who were most of them foreigners, had been hoarded onto a cattle truck.
As far as I understood from this passage, the relative clause "who were most of them foreigners" is correct. Therefore, (2) containing it is also correct.
But to me, "foreigners" going right after "most of them" seems correct only in (1), but not in (2).
So, is "who were most of them foreigners" really correct?
If it is, then how to explain that two noun phrases ("most of them" and "foreigners") can stand in a row in (2)?

update №1:
Must "most of them" be set off with pauses: "who were [pause] most of them [pause] foreigners"?
Wouldn't it be better to set off "most of them" with commas: "who were, most of them, foreigners"?

update №2:
The tourists, most of them foreigners, ... – I think "most of them" can stand with "foreigners" because there is an omitted verb between them: "the tourists, most of them were foreigners, ..."
The tourists, who were most of them foreigners, ... – I think this is ungrammatical because I can't use the logic about an omitted verb here since the following is obviously incorrect: "the tourists, who were most of them were foreigners, ..."

I would say that "who were most of them foreigners, " reads quite odd, but that "most of them foreigners, " is fine. But that is only intuition, not something I could explain in any formal manner.

I edited your title to match the actual sentence.

It think it is an awkward example given in the book. The "who were ..." should probably convey the idea of a relative clause beginning with "who". But to be a "nice sounding" sentence in the plural case, you would use either the suggested "..., most of whom were foreigners, ..." or "..., who mostly were foreigners, ..." or "..., who were foreigners in the majority of cases, ..." or something like that.

@MichaelHarvey Please reread the original post once again. The CGEL says (1) is correct. I accept it because (1) seems grammatical to me. Also, as I understood, CGEL says (2) is correct too. But (2) looks ungrammatical to me. So my question is about (2).

Is it really "hoarded"?  Boarded would make more sense.

No, the relative clause: who were most of them foreigners is most definitely not correct. The textbook provides the comparison to show it's wrong.

@Lambie - it's OK where I come from

@Lambie A bit old-fashioned, that's all. But he did not run after the unmarried girls, especially the rich heiresses who were most of them plain. There was a special reason for this War and peace, Leo Tolstoy; For the Persians fell boldly on the men, who were most of them unarmed Arrian, The Anabasis of Alexander, (translated by Edward James Chinnock 1884); seventeen able hands were listed on the part of Virginia, who were most of them Indian traders and expert woodsmen. the History of the Dividing Line Betwixt Virginia and North Carolina (William Byrd 1841)

@MichaelHarvey No, it is not fine in this day and age. We ain't in the 1800s. But keep googling.

@Lambie - my mother and her generation used to say things like that, and Gertrude Stein wrote: They are all of them repeating and I hear it. I love it and I tell it. I love it and now I will write it. This is now a history of my love of it. I hear it and I love it and I write it. . . . They live it and I hear it and I see it and I love it and now and always I will write it. 1910 approx.

@Lambie - it is too absolutely fine 'in this day and age' for any writing that aspires to rise above the Facebook/X/SMS level.

@Lambie - maybe you should try a bit of Googling yourself? It's amazing what you can find out.

@MichaelHarvey Gertrude Stein? Please. She is like an AmE James Joyce. Maybe you should ask FF if he approves of it. It is just sloppy. The cars, which were most of them blue, did not etc.

@Lambie - I'll concede Stein :-)

Since it seems to you vital, can you say
When to you "foreigners" going right after "most of them" seems correct only in (1), but not in (2) is that purely about '…who were…' or does something else matter?

(1) already gives "most of whom were foreigners". Also, the simpler "mostly foreigners" is ok.

@JackO'Flaherty or hoarded --> herded (onto a cattle truck).

@Lambie Thanks and how is that helpful, here or anywhere?
Whatever I've failed to explain, I stand to justify.
If you'd like some kind of private discussion that could be fine, though I have no idea how to initiate such…
In the mean time, I'm not making a complaint but how is that Comment even allowed on SE?

@Lambie Thanks and at risk of us being blown into Chat, what did you not understand here, please?

@Robbie Goodwin Since it seems to you vital, can you say When to you "foreigners" going right after "most of them" seems correct only in (1), but not in (2) is that purely about '…who were…'

@Lambie I like Gertrude Stein the way I like Walt Whitman, Robert Frost (and always) Marianne Moore.

@RobbieGoodwin To answer your question, I added update №2 into the original post. Could you please comment it? Thanks.

The tourist, most of them foreigners, etc. is an apposition.  There is just no need for: were.

@Loviii In update №2 ‘the tourists, most of them were foreigners, … ’ can never work as it stands, so it cannot justify anything else.
It would work with ’whom’ instead of ‘them’, as ‘the tourists, most of whom were foreigners, … ’
It would work with parenthetical separation, as ‘the tourists - most of them were foreigners - … ’

@Lambie Thanks and another time, why not use 'I don't understand (whatever)…' perhaps with '… because (reason) …' rather than anything so vague as 'I cannot understand many of your comments...'?

I assume the OP is bothered by "explicit repetition" of the subject in the cited context. It's still perfectly grammatical - it's just that we don't often do this today...


A lovely peak around 1890. Perfect validation in my view.

Apparently, after 1890, there have been sporadic attempts to introduce We are mostly familiar for this context. But that just doesn't work, imho, because mostly collates forwards. To adjectival familiar, in my context, as opposed to the noun foreigners in OP's case. Nowadays we avoid repeating the primary subject (we, us in my case, tourists, them in OP's). Most of us are familiar... The tourists, mostly foreigners...

I added two questions into the original post: 1) Must "most of them" be set off with pauses: "who were [pause] most of them [pause] foreigners"?; 2) Wouldn't it be better to set off "most of them" with commas: "who were, most of them, foreigners"? Could you please answer them? Thanks.

You have to have pauses / commas before and after the entire clause "who were most of them foreigners", otherwise it will appear to be a restrictive clause (specifically singling out those tourists who were in fact foreigners). But your idea about adding more pauses is just weird - it does nothing useful, and it's inherently distracting in a context where the main two commas / pauses must be present to convey the intended meaning. The main point is that who were most of them foreigners is a "dated" verbose construction compared to who were mostly foreigners.

One of the concerns of the OP is how two noun phrases ("most of them" and "foreigners") can stand in a row.
But most of them has an adjectival force. It qualifies the word foreigners. You can see that if you omit most of them:

The tourists, (who were) foreigners, had been hoarded onto a cattle truck.

Here all of the tourists are foreigners. Adding most of them simply qualifies that fact.

I added two questions into the original post: 1) Must "most of them" be set off with pauses: "who were [pause] most of them [pause] foreigners"?; 2) Wouldn't it be better to set off "most of them" with commas: "who were, most of them, foreigners"? Could you please answer them? Thanks.

(1) I just tried saying the sentence aloud, and I didn't feel it necessary to pause where you have suggested. (2) Commas are possible but in my view not necessary. I wouldn't add them. The sentence is clear to me without them.
